# tab widget text below the tab

Tags: android

i am new to android and had create the tabhost with two tabwidget all thing goes ok and fine and now i am displaying two different activity with two tab also.but the question is the text which i am specifying for two different tab is coming below while running the app.Below i am putting the screenshot for understanding

Screenshot:
[image]

the text are mark as red so is there any way to align that text  to the center.
one more thing i m also using the drawable image for different state of user click.
thanks for any help.

**the xml file for the tabhost**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <include layout="@layout/top_portion_layout"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
           >
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#808080">
            </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

the portion is another layout which having two button sync all and home
which i am including in this layout

Comment: Show the layout xml file? You might be a victim of padding.

Comment: what's topportion layout??

Answer (score 0):

**inspite of**

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

**you should use**

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

**inside tab_host element**